# ¿Ordenar una lista de objetos por uno de sus atributos en c#?

Tags: c#, lista, archivo

Mi problema es que tengo un archivo de texto en el cual tengo varios productos ya creados pero necesito ordenarlos por su categoria y mostrarlos en un listbox.La lista del archivo es la siguiente:

1. Mostaza,500,20,3333,Aderezo
2. Oregano,300,1,4444,Condimento
3. Mayonesa,700,35,1111,Aderezo

El ultimo atributo seria la categoria

Les agradeceria un monton la ayuda

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Lectura obligatoria.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tu modelo es el siguiente

```
class Model
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Num { get; set; }
   public Category { get; set; }
   // ...
}
```

Y tienes una lista `List<Model>`, usando `System.Linq` puedes ordenarla por el campo que desees

```
// list -> List<Model>
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(m => m.Category);
```

Comment: Lo he probado y al llamarlo al listbox no me sale nada como si el boton no ejecuta nada